# extract certain columns from data frame based on given column names

Tags: r

I have a data frame, `A`, which has 30 columns. Right now, I have a vector B, which is shown as follows.

```
B<-c("t1","ABC","XYZ")
```

I would like to extract the three columns from A which correspond to the three column names shown in B. How to do that in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you are looking for something like this.

```
A <- data.frame(a = 1:5, t1 = 1:5, bc = 1:5, ABC = 1:5, XYZ = 1:5)
B <- c("t1","ABC","XYZ") 

# A
#  a t1 bc ABC XYZ
#1 1  1  1   1   1
#2 2  2  2   2   2
#3 3  3  3   3   3
#4 4  4  4   4   4
#5 5  5  5   5   5

A[, B]

#  t1 ABC XYZ
#1  1   1   1
#2  2   2   2
#3  3   3   3
#4  4   4   4
#5  5   5   5
```